# libgdx moving animated actor following the finger touch

Tags: touch, libgdx, move, actor

In my game one crocodile is in water i have to guide that crocodile in water ,
it will follow my finger touch and will finish the path.

it should rotate when there is turn.

what approach should i use in libgdx...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is only one approach.
You capture the input (implement InputListener), unproject the pointer to your game world (Camera.unproject(...)), calculate the difference between the target vector and the position of the object that should follow it and move it in this direction, or use A* in case there are obstacles in between, calculate an appropriate path and then move along that path.